# Laravel authorization call wrong policy

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I created all the policies with command artisan, `php artisan make:policy ModelPolicy --model=ModelName`, created `UserPolicy` and `ProfilePolicy`, the first one works fine, but the second one (`ProfilePolicy`) is calling UserPolicy.

ProiflePolicy.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Profile;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;

class ProfilePolicy {

    use HandlesAuthorization;

    // I'm use this to know what policy is being called
    protected $template = '[ProfilePolicy] you cannot %s this resource!';

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user) {
        return in_array( $user->profile->slug, ['administrator'] )
            ? Response::allow() 
            : Response::deny( sprintf( $this->template, 'LIST') );
    }
    
    ...
```

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Profile;
use App\Policies\ProfilePolicy;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // \App\Models\User::class => \App\Policies\UserPolicy::class,
        Profile::class => ProfilePolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

ProfileController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\v0;

use App\Models\Profile;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ProfilerController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function index( Request $request ) {

        $query =  Profile::query();

        // UserPolicy is being called even commented
        \Gate::authorize('viewAny', auth('staff')->user() );
        
        query_page( $query, $request );

        query_embed( new Profile, $query, $request );

        $query->when( in_array(auth('staff')->user()->profile->slug, ['seller-manager']), function( $query ) {
            return $query->whereSlug( 'seller' );
        });
        
        $data = $query->limit( $request->limit ?: config('app.limit_per_page') )->get();

        return response()->json( responseFormat( false, $data ) );
    }
    ....
```

API Response:
[image]

Comment: ofcourse it is using the Policy for a `User` since you are passing a `User` object to the gate

Comment: omg! you right! i misunderstood the laravel doc!